# How to fix "driver not found error" in Symfony and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, symfony

I'm using Symfony 4 and PostgreSQL. I was able to insert mock data into my database with fixtures, however when I want to insert data from a form or make a selection query on the available data in my database it shows me this error:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you only set .env.local file and not the .env ?

Comment: Yes, it means your .env file is missing database configuration. When using symfony in cli it merges both config and you can have test, local and production environment config seprate with such mechanism. Check .env file and make sure your database parameters are correct